# What is the redirect url for a mvc site hosted on localhost machine with iis

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.1

Created a mvc .net core 2.1 web app using azure active directory authorization. When developing in visual studio using iisexpress it works like it should, sign into azure account and I have access. After I publish it to my local folder, add website and bind the address in iis and go to address http://localhost:100 I get the Microsoft sign in page. I log in and get AADSTS50011 error.

[image]

So I go to the azure active directory portal -> App Registrations -> my Mvc project -> Authentication.
In the list of redirect url's theres a record for iisexpress: https://localhost:44324/signin-oidc
ok fine, so I add my localhost address from my website on iis http://localhost:100 , doesn't work, tried http://localhost:100/signin-oidc. No luck.
In the url response page with the error it has the redirect uri as what I've entered in azure?

https://login.microsoftonline.com/0e424d28-7904-47e1-bf7e-253bb7f43814/oauth2/authorize?client_id=7f725dcc-36f7-4f04-83fa-a29c8d7ea604&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F10.0.0.44%3A100%2Fsignin-oidc&.........

What am I missing. I've beat my head on this added https to the sites bindings, same result. Is this a kestrel thing, redirecting from iis as the proxy? I've tried putting the kestrel default addresses that are used when kestrel is the only server https://localhost:5001 and http://localhost:5000. Is there some code that I need to change to use it as a production app.

Comment: stdout log file:
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Users\Howard\source\repos\FRTOOLS_MVC_PROJECT\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish
Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:18829
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
Application is shutting down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostname in iis binding settings needs to be *
[image]

Also if you want to connect to your site on a the local network from remote machines you need to add a redirect url in the azure application list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry you are having this problem. The reply URL in the configuration of your code just needs to match exactly what you have in the portal. Try setting both to your main homepage URL. Also, make sure that the Tenant ID in your code matches the Tenant ID in the portal, and the App ID in the portal and Client ID in the code are matching. You can search your code to see if there's maybe an incorrect reference in your web config or app settings.

[image]

If you have a published web page and are hosting this somewhere, the the reply url needs to match whatever published page you want your user to be redirected to (myapp.azurewebsites.net). If it works on local but doesn't work when you publish then you need to add your published app URL.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but the problem came down to the hostname in iis binding. the value needs to be *.

Comment: You should add this as an answer and mark it as verified so that others searching can see more clearly :)